# How to perform internal recording of application's audio in iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio-recording

I want to record the sounds that are played in the application running on iphone but not record surrounding sounds from mic. So please help me how to perform internal audio recording

Answer (score -1):

Refer to apple docs on AVAudioRecorder :

[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

It's available since iOS 4.